# Conditional statement inside Spring config

Tags: spring

How to have conditional statement within a spring configuration file

I have String bean (b) whose value depends on the value of a property (a). a is set dynamically based on environment it runs.

```
if (a)
 b="yes"
else
 b="no"
```

How do i code this in spring config?

Comment: jeejava.com/conditional-statement-in-spring-config/

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As Ryan said [SpEL](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) can help. You should be able to do something like this in Spring xml:

```
<bean id="flag" class="java.lang.Boolean">
    <constructor-arg value="#{ systemProperties['system.propery.flag'] ?: false }" />
</bean>

<bean id="bean" class="com.my.MyBean">
    <property name="property" value="#{ flag ? 'yes' : 'no' }"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this...It works.. Given Roll,Location,name is in property file and I am reading it above this line.

```xml
<bean id="Student" class="beans.Student">
    <property name="name" value="#{ ${Roll}== 1 ? '${Location}' : '${name}' }"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

See [Spring Expression Language](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) for Spring 3+. Otherwise, you're probably stuck with writing a [FactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html) or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

below is working for me.
system property passed as `java -Dflag=true -jar project.jar`

```
<bean id="flag" class="java.lang.Boolean">
  <constructor-arg value="#{ systemProperties['flag'] ?: false }"/>
</bean>

<bean id="bean" class="com.my.MyBean">
  <property name="property" value="#{ flag ? 'yes' : 'no' }"/>
</bean>
```