# How to initialize a set in a spring bean using value from .properties file

Tags: java, spring, properties, configuration-files

I have a spring bean (let's call it `MagicBean`) which has a `HashSet<String>` as one of its properties.

I know how to init a set like this:

```
<bean id="mySet" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.SetFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetSetClass" value="java.util.HashSet"/>
    <property name="sourceSet">
        <set>
            <value>Value 1</value>
            <value>Value 2</value>
            <value>Value 3</value>
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="magicBean" class="MagicBean">
    <property name="mySet" ref="mySet"/>
</bean>
```

Is there a way to set the values in the set using values from .properties file instead of hard-coding those value in the xml?

**Update 1:**
Since I might have different numbers of values for this set in different environments, using the hard-coded set in the xml won't work. That's why I need to somehow fetch these values from a properties file.

**Update 2:**
I came up with a quick-and-dirty way to do this which is list all values as ONE single string in the .properties file and then set this value to the `MagicBean`. Then in Java code, parse this string.
Any better idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
<value>${my.set.value1}/value>
```

And set the value in property file:

```
my.set.value1=Value1
```

Comment: But I don't know how many values I will have. I might have different numbers of values for this set in different environments.

Comment: So how can you declare it in your xml?

Comment: Ah, what I meant from my previous comment was that what I'm getting at. I might have different numbers of values for this set in different environments, thus using the hard-coded set in the xml won't work. That's why I need to get these values from a properties file

Comment: Ok I see. Take a look at these (not set specific but conditional sprin config) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035630/how-to-achieve-conditional-resource-import-in-a-spring-xml-context and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906863/conditional-statement-inside-spring-config

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
                           ">
    <bean class="B1">
        <property name="Props">
            <util:properties location="classpath:test.properties" />
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

this is B1

```
class B1 {
    public void setProps(Properties props) {
        ...
    }
}
```