# Spring Profile in the spring xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

I have two property objects as ::

```
<util:map id="property1"> </util:map>

<util:map id="property2"> </util:map>
```

To decide on which property to use I am using:

```
<bean id="properties"
    class="com.Properties"
    factory-method="getProperties">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="property1" />
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="property2" />
    <constructor-arg index="2" value="${propertytouse:false}" />
</bean>
```

The problem with this approach is I have to use a static method for decision making. I was wondering if there is any other way to declare the bean in order to make the decision.

Comment: Which version Spring are you using?  Have you looked at [Spring profiles](http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-spring-profiles-xml)?

Comment: I am not even looking at profiles but I was wondering if there any way to execute this if condition. I want to choose a bean based on condition.

Comment: How about [Spring expression language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906863/conditional-statement-inside-spring-config)?