# Set the property based on condition in spring xml?

Tags: java, spring

I want to include the file under spring.xml based on condition like

```
<bean id="ehcache" class="com.MyCustomBean" scope="singleton">
        if({environment==dev})
           <property name="fileLoc" value="file_dev.xml" />
         else
           <property name="fileLoc" value="file_prod.xml" />

    </bean>
```

where `environment` is property defined under property file.

For information, I am already using spring `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` to   resolves `${...}` placeholders within bean definition property values .

Comment: What about this solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906863/conditional-statement-inside-spring-config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider to use the spring profile, you can divide the xml files to different config files
please refer to https://dzone.com/articles/using-spring-profiles-xml

Answer (score 2):

You should do

```
<property name="name" value="#{ ${environment}== dev ? file_dev.xml : file_prod.xml }"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar case, but I needed to inject different beans depending on property: "my.property". In my case this solution was successful

```
 <property name="name" ref="#{ ${my.property:false}==true ? 'bean1' : 'bean2' }"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A workaround solution:
<import resource="file_${env:dev}.xml"/>
file_dev.xml
file_prod.xml
```

Comment: Due to https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-1358, this solution doesnt work. Only system properties are evaulated. Kind of a chicken/egg problem.