# Spring: instantiate a class depending on String parameter

Tags: java, spring

I have a syntax similar to this in my spring application:

```
public OAuthClient getOAuthClient(String clientType, ClientConfig config){
    switch (clientType) {
        case "google":
            return new GoogleOAuthClient(config);
        case "facebook":
            return new FacebookOauthClient(config);
        case "linkedIn":
            return new LinkedInOauthClient(config);
        //... more clients
        default:
            return new BasicOauthClient(config);
    }
}
```

How to manage such instantiation with Spring xml-configuration?

Comment: You have no return type in method

Comment: A return type is missing in the code.

Comment: Thanks, corrected

Comment: Where does `config` come from?

Comment: From database. `ClientConfig` does not depend on `clientType`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional statement inside Spring config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906863/conditional-statement-inside-spring-config)

Comment: Would you like to create OAuthClient object as managed bean?

Comment: @KenBekov, not obviously. I want Spring to instantiate a class based on some `Collection` or `Map` containing `String`-`Class` reference to get rid of `select` or `if` statements.

Answer (score 3):

It is little bit unclear what you going to do. But if you would like to have `OAuthClient` as managed bean and its creation based on some conditions, you can use factory. First create factory class:

```
public class OAuthClientFactory{
    public OAuthClient createOAuthClient(String clientType, ClientConfig config){
       //Conditional creation logic...
    } 
}
```

Now in xml-configuration declare beans:

```
<bean id="authClientFactory" class="com.somepackage.OAuthClientFactory"/>
<bean id="clientConfig" class="com.somepackage.ClientConfig"/>

<bean id="authClient" class="com.somepackage.OAuthClient " factory-bean="authClientFactory" 
  factory-method="createOAuthClient">
    <constructor-arg value="google"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="clientConfig"/>
</bean>
```

`ClinetConfig` also have to be managed bean for pass it as parameter into factory method. For make example simpler I just declared it as bean, but in real code you should decide how to create it.

---

According to your last comments you need to instantiate client instances on demand. And you would like to avoid any conditional operations and make it by "spring way". Then you should register all types of clients as bean with corresponding name.

If you need to create new instance every time you request for new client, you should declare it as `prototype` bean:

```
...
<bean id="googleClient" class="com.somepackage.GoogleOAuthClient" scope="prototype"/>
<bean id="facebookClient" class="com.somepackage.FacebookOauthClient" scope="prototype"/>
...
```

Or if you need just one (singleton) instance of every requested client declare it as `lazy-init`:

```
...
<bean id="googleClient" class="com.somepackage.GoogleOAuthClient" lazy-init="true"/>
<bean id="facebookClient" class="com.somepackage.FacebookOauthClient" lazy-init="true"/>
...
```

In both cases instances of client will be created only by demand. Now you can get instance of client by requesting from `ApplicationContext`:

```
@Service
public class SomeService{

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    public void SomeMethod(){
        ClientConfig config = ... //obtain client config
        GoogleOAuthClient client = (GoogleOAuthClient)context.getBean("googleClient", config);
    }
}
```

Or if you don't use annotation based injection, then implement [ApplicationContextAware](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware.html) interface to get `ApplicationContext`.

Comment: The question is how to get rid of this ugly select which will be used here as well inside `OAuthClientFactory#createOAuthClient`

Answer (score 2):

You can autowire the list of classes implementing or extending OAuthClient. You'll be able to select the good one if you have a "getName()" method for instance :

```
@Autowired
List<OAuthClient> clients;
public OAuthClient getOAuthClient(String clientType, ClientConfig config){
     foreach (OAuthClient client : clients) {
         if (client.getName().equals(clientType)) {
            return client;
         }
    }
     // Return null or throw exception
     return null;
}
```

Comment: OK, but this requires to have a list of instances and I need to instantiate on demand with constructor arguments.

Comment: So you don't want to instantiate using spring ?

Comment: You use reflection to create instances : you may create a Map assiociating name to class, after this you invoke using reflection.

Comment: That's what I'm doing. `clientClass.getConstructor(ClientConfig.class).newInstance(config);` I just want to know if Spring can do it more gracefully.